# Protecting GET request within Django web application

Tags: python, django, api, rest

How do I protect specific GET request (for example: `^api/...`)?

I want to make this view (API call) available to only my Django web application.

It should only be called by Django web application, not directly.

Is it a good practice to use hash key generated by CSRF Middle-ware? Is there any better approach?

Comment: how are you going to call it? An ajax call? Or just internally, as a web service for your own app.

Comment: @santiagobasulto It is an Ajax call, I don't want to make the API available to public. Idea is to use this API only via Web Application that I'm building.

Comment: I'm curious about this too and wondering why it isn't common to extend CSRF to cover this? Or at least it doesn't seem to be documented in the django docs. It seems like all the AJAX calls could be switched to POST to trigger the CSRF protection but that feels pretty hacky.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there are no reliable ways to achieve this. The best way I can think of, is generating some sort of private key in your javascript client, and ofuscate the code. That'd make it hard for "an attaker" to use your methods. Maybe using HMAC, or something like that.

An example. You want to make the following call: `/api/users/1/vote_up`. You could have some code to generate your private key:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js">

var hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, generatePassphraseObfuscated());
hmac.update("/api/users/1/vote_up");
var hash = hmac.finalize();
$.ajax(
    /api/users/1/vote_up,
    {hash: hash}
)
</script>
```

The `generatePassphraseObfuscated` function is the key. You need to make it really hard to replicate. Also, you could change it in every request and add a cookie to identify which "version" you sent. For example, you could have two versions:

```
function generatePassphraseObfuscated(){
    return 1;
}

function generatePassphraseObfuscated(){
    return 2;
}
```

And serve them randomly, and identify it with a cookie. So you know which to use in your django view.

Again, it's not reliable, there's no foolproof way to do what you want to do. It's just a silly way to make it ugly for other people to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these [replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686893/restrict-access-to-a-django-view-only-from-the-server-itself-localhost), they seem to have gone through this same issue. I'd write a decorator that checks if `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the same as your local address.